# Debugging xv6 using QEMU and GDB: cannot resolve name: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: gdb, qemu, xv6

As stated in the title, I'm trying to use QEMU and GDB to debug xv6 as part of an OS project.

I'm able to `make qemu` and `make qemu-nox` perfectly, but when I run
`make qemu-gdb` or `make qemu-nox-gdb` the command hangs and the output is like:

> qemu-system-i386 -nographic -drive file=fs.img,index=1,media=disk,format=raw -drive file=xv6.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw -smp 1 -m 512  -S -gdb tcp::25502

with no prompt showing up.

When I try connect using GDB the result is:

> localhost:25502: cannot resolve name: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Anyone able to troubleshoot? Thanks!

Info:
Development OS: Mac OS X Mojave
QEMU: qemu-system-i386 (installed using Homebrew)
GDB: 8.3 (installed using Homebrew)
Cross-compile toolchain: compiled from source code